# Using dynamic/deep linking with Firebase email verification?

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-firebase

I am using RNfirebase with my react-native app. I can get the email verification link to open-up my app but that's about it. I know that I need to access the link and parse it to get the oobCode and apply it to the user. However, when I open my app using the link, the listeners I trigger using { Linking } from 'react-native' do not seem to detect the url. I want to redirect them to the "Thank you for verifying your email" page as well as verify their email using the oobCode generated by firebase.

I have manipulated my AndroidManifest.xml to listen in on the links (myapp.page.link)

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
          <data
              android:scheme="https"
              android:host="myapp.page.link"
              />
      </intent-filter>
```

I have added listeners in my initial app page.

```
useEffect(() => {
getLink()
Linking.addEventListener('url', appWokeUp)
}, [])

const getLink = async() => {
        const link = await Linking.getInitialURL()
        console.log(link)
    }

    const appWokeUp = event => {
        console.log(event.url)
    }
```

All I receive is 'null' from getLink(). I don't receive anything at all from the appWokeUp handler. I'm expecting to receive the url at least that triggered the app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `firebase.links().onLink()`  and `firebase.getInitialUrl()` to get the link.
2. Then parse the querystring and use the parameter `oobCode`
3. Call `firebase.auth().applyActionCode()`

Comment: in my onLink I am just getting the deep link without any parameters... any ideas on how I can actually retrieve the code?

Comment: Are you using `onLink` from `firebase.links()` ? In your example it looks like you are using the one from react-native(Linking)